# KLEE: ERROR: Loading file /usr/local/lib/klee/runtime/klee-uclibc.bca failed: Invalid record

Tags: c, clang, llvm, klee

When running KLEE with `klee --libc=uclibc --posix-runtime --external-calls=all program.bc`, it gives me this error:

```
KLEE: NOTE: Using POSIX model: /usr/local/lib/klee/runtime/libkleeRuntimePOSIX64_Debug+Asserts.bca

KLEE: ERROR: Loading file /usr/local/lib/klee/runtime/klee-uclibc.bca failed: Invalid record
```

I search for similar questions here http://mailman.ic.ac.uk/pipermail/klee-dev/2017-May/001602.html.

After using `llvm-config --version`, the version of llvm that is installed is 10.0.0

Then use `clang --version` , it gives this:
`clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /usr/bin`

Their versions match.

Now I don't know what is going on, can someone help me here?

Comment: Following that mailing list answer: What LLVM version is you KLEE version linked against? What LLVM version is your klee-uclibc built with?

Comment: LLVM 11 is my KLEE version linked against. Same version for klee-uclibc. Just in case I made any mistakes, do you know the way how to verify this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem because I moved the klee executable in docker, guessing that the file it depends on cannot find the executable at this time. I restarted docker and it worked fine. Hope my answer helps you!